# C# - Strategy for TDD when prototyping

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I find that some forms of writing code lend themselves better to TDD than others.  Especially, red-green refactor testing.

In Red/Green refactor, I start with all my unit tests in place and failing (red).  Then I implement my code until all test pass (green).

For example, if I have an interface that needs to be implemented 10-20x then I simply implement the interface in a class, which sets all methods to throw `NotImplementedException`.  Then, create a test for each public method.  From there, I just write the code to fix the tests.

Processes aren't always so straight forward.  For example, I'm writing a basic Excel parser.  I'm not familiar with the Excel Interop API.  I find it easier to simply write code.  Then, through trial and error I discover my class design.

In this case I am writing some junk software.  Prototyping it out just so I can figure out what my design needs to be.  (Maybe I need to pass in a fileName here, maybe to this constructor...).

Ultimately, I would like to keep TDD.  I do believe it keeps my code minimal and [lean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_manufacturing).

Does TDD work for prototyping?  In other words, is there an approach I can follow so as to allow TDD to work for me even when I am not entirely sure where my design is going?

Comment: In your case with this type of problem I believe you want to approach it with BDD instead of TDD.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development

Comment: A big part of mastering a technique is knowing when to apply it.  While learning a technique, it's valuable to apply it to a wide range of problems, so that you can gain experience.  Once you've gained that experience, however, you can evaluate whether any given problem is well-suited to each technique at your disposal.  If you find that prototyping is less productive using TDD, there's no need to use it for that case.

Comment: Let me first state I have not found the value in TDD for myself.  However, my understanding of "TDD" principles are you write a failing test - then write just enough code to make it pass.  The way you are approaching this you are writing all the tests then writing the code to make them all pass.  I'm not sure how well that would "drive" your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but do it like an API. Instead of guessing how to do something with excel, decide what you want to do as an end result. (Example: Read Cells A0 to A100)

Then as you go along with how it will work behind that interface, you will end up seeing what it is you can break off and test by itself, and possibly what might work better for the design. (Example: write code to read 0,0 to 0,100 and remove the letter code as it is more complex without any gain)

Don't be afraid of invalidating tests due to design/behavior changes, they are there to help, not be concrete. (Example: That original test to read cells A0 to A100 should be deleted)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you would have a couple of options:

- seperate the concerns and abstract away the complex behaviour to an
  interface. You can then use the interface to create a Mock object
  (http://code.google.com/p/moq/)
- Use Pex & Moles to create a Mole for your excel api (again this focusses on seperating   isolating the concerns of your code..) and use the mole instead of the real API in your unit test

pretty sure people have much more suggestions but these are two of my favorite approaches